# How to check for white spaces and special characters

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to code a form for a login using php to check it. But I can't get it to check the if I have any whitespaces and special characters for the username. I tried using the [\W]+ but that did not work.

```
       <?php

        $usernerr = "";
        $passwerr = "";
        $usern = "";
        $passw = "";
        $pattern = '/[\'\/~`\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|;:"\<\>,\.\?\\\]/';
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {   
            if(empty($_POST['uname']))
            {
                $usernerr = "*Please add a username please!";
            }
        else
        { 
            $usern = clearInput($_POST['uname']);
            if(!preg_match('/s/', $usern) || !preg_match($pattern, $usern))
            {
                $usernerr = "*Username have only letters and numbers!";
            }
            $usernerr = "";
        }

        if(empty($_POST['psw']))
        {
            $passwerr = "*Please add a password please!";
        }
        else
        { 
            $passw = clearInput($_POST['psw']);
            $passwerr = "";
        }
    }   

    function clearInput($input)
    {
        $input = trim($input);
        $input = stripslashes($input);
        $input = htmlspecialchars($input);
        return $input;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Instead of checking for specific forbidden characters, check if the string contains anything other than the allowed characters.

Comment: I'd use http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php If `Username have only letters and numbers` are the rules. I also would remove that `clearInput` function, is that to prevent SQL injections or XSS?

Comment: Also, everytime I see functions like your `checkInput()`, I cringe. That usually means that you're doing something wrong. If it is there for protecting yourself against SQL injections, it's not good enough. Also, escaping and changing the password is a bad idea. Let's keep the password as is, since you're only suppose to store the password hash anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the error message you wrote, you are complicating yourself.

Instead of searching for the list of characters that aren't alpha num, search for alpha num only. Try using [this](https://regex101.com/r/eiuvMU/2) pattern, and don't negate the condition.

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/";
// Some code...
if(preg_match($pattern, $usern))
// ^-------------------------------Notice the changes
{
    //Username is valid
}
```

Description of the pattern :

`^` from the begining

`[a-zA-Z0-9]` search an alpha num

`+` 1 or more time

`$` to the end

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`can be replaced by `/^[[:alnum:]]+$/` or `/^[a-z\d]+$/i` which produce the same effect.

Comment: There also is posix character class, `[[:alnum:]]`. I find `[a-z\d]` with `i` modifier, or what your wrote easier though